# Enforcing fingerprint if user authentication is required for every use of the key

Tags: android, android-keystore

In the process of starting using Android Keystore in my app, I was going through the documentation of [setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)) api, which states that :

> Additionally, if the key requires that user authentication takes place for every use of the key (see setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int)), at least one fingerprint must be enrolled (see hasEnrolledFingerprints()).

I am curious why fingerprint is enforced here.

Why am I not allowed to use normal device lock if I want user authentication to take place for every use of the key?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.